# How was Poe Dameron tortured for information?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I read [the wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IT-000-XZ_1594) and it said a droid used methods 2265, 6304, 3333, and K8-A4, but what did the droid do?

In *The Force Awakens*, Poe Dameron is captured and tortured for information on the map to Luke Skywalker, it is said that the droid asked 813 times and when the ace spat on the thing, it proceeded to use the methods above. What I want to know is what exactly are the methods and how are they done?

Comment: I doubt any explicit definitions exist. The implication is that the First Order uses so many varied torture techniques that they needed to be catalogued and given distinct identifiers.

Comment: Also, in some cases, it's more horrifying for the reader/viewer to be told something like this simple list of methods by reference number (and let them imagine their own worst fears, like Room 101 in *1984*, than to detail the exact torture applied (which invariably some readers will find less distasteful than others).

Comment: There's a quote from the Wheel of Time for that: "I do not know. But they did not, either. That is the trick of it; their minds made up worse than I ever could. I have seen a tough man break when I sent for a basket of figs and some mice."

Answer (score 4):

The sole reference to this torture comes from the *[Poe Dameron: Flight Log](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Poe_Dameron:_Flight_Log)* in-universe scrapbook. Nothing else is known of these procedures, other than that they were applied by the interrogation droid that was tasked with interrogating Poe and that procedure K8-04 apparently involves some kind of shock (possibly electrical in nature) applied to the victim's nervous system.

> The IT unit proceeded to apply methods 2265, 6304. 3333, and
> KB-A4 to the prisoner. The prisoner reacted violently to procedure
> KB-A4 and nearly swallowed his tongue. **The IT unit increased the
> neuroshock amplitude** and repeated the question: Where is the
> map to Luke Sky walker?

Interestingly, in the [Force Awakens novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization)), the main torture he suffered was at the hands of his captors, in the form of punishment beatings.

> So sunk was he in depression that he scarcely reacted when they beat
> him. Delivered with practiced skill, designed to hurt but not result
> in permanent damage, the blows fell intermittently, at different times
> of the day on different parts of his body. He did his best to shut out
> the pain, much as he succeeded in shutting out the questions. What he
> did not know was that they were merely a softening-up, an introduction
> to his principal interrogator.